# Add-on for IE8 only visible when I debug it from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer-8, bho

I am following the C++ example for creating a BHO for Internet Explorer 8 here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250489.aspx

I managed to compile and debug the extension without a problem (I use Visual Studio 2010). If IE was started from the debugger I can see all my addons in IE when I click "Tools" -> "Manage Add-Ons". However, when I start IE8 directly (by double-clicking its icon) - I do not see the addons. I am 100% sure that I have registered the addons with regsvr32.exe .
I even tried to run IE8 "as administator", but nothing changed.

Why are my addons disappearing when I start IE8 without using the debugger ?

Comment: Just a thought, but if you have a 64bit system, could it be that under the debugger you are running a 32bit IE while from the desktop you launch 64bit IE? Then, if you ran regsvr32.exe from the SysWOW directory it would make sense  that only the 32bit IE sees the add-on, but it's just a plain guess.

Comment: Thank you - you are right. In the debugger I specify this command:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

And when I run IE8 directly it is from here:
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

What is the correct way to register the BHO with both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of IE ?

Comment: You cant't register a 32b BHO for IE 64b. First task: succcesfully build a 64 bits version of your BHO :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a 64bit system, chances are that under the debugger you are running a 32bit IE while from the desktop you launch 64bit IE. Then, if you ran regsvr32.exe from the SysWOW64 directory it would make sense that only the 32bit IE sees the add-on.

To overcome this you need to:

- Make a 64bit version of your solution, creating a 64bit build configuration in Visual Studio is quite clearly explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9yb4317s.aspx)
- Register the produced dll with the regsvr32 from C:\Windows\System32 not C:\Windows\SysWOW64